# User agent string for "[browser version] and later"

Tags: php, http, user-agent

I'm trying to avoid tons of PHP code by specifying that a remote stylesheet, containing CSS animation, should be loaded if the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string corresponds to [browser version x] or later. For example, knowing that CSS animations are supported in Chrome 19 and newer, the code would detect if Chrome's version is greater than 19, and load the appropriate stylesheet.
Is this feasible at all using PHP?

Comment: What exactly do `tons of php code` have to do with a css file containing animations? That might influence the answers.

Comment: Admittedly, I could've made that clearer.<br>
I'm not terribly experienced in PHP, so so far, the only way I know how to actually re-create this effect is by having separate conditional stylesheet loads for each browser version. I'd have to add a new comment with every new version of every browser. Obviously, this isn't a viable solution.

Comment: I believe that I'll go with Modernizr, but it'd still be interesting to know how this can be done with PHP.

Comment: Note that browsers just ignore stuff in style-sheets that they don't understand, so unless you are offering different solutions for different browsers (css vs javascript), you can just include the animations in your main style-sheet.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do here. I'm using CanIUse to find out which features are supported beginning in which browser version, and providing fallbacks based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* use PHP for this, then there is a built-in function [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) that does what you want.

However... If you use `get_browser()`, be aware that it is a bad solution to your problem.

In order to user this function, you must have an up-to-date `browsecap.ini` file, which is basically a text file that defines the capabilities of every browser and every version ever released.

The downsides of this are obvious:

- You have to find and install an up-to-date copy of browsecap.ini in the first place.
- You have to update it every time a new browser is released (and new versions are coming out frequently, so this is quite a big task).
- It might not include all features that you want to detect.
- It will break if the user masks their user agent string.

For all these reasons, I strongly recommend not using `get_browser()`, or indeed any PHP-based or server-side solution.

Instead, as others have said, you should investigate using the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) library. This is a Javascript library that you install on your site that does feature detection in the browser. It will never be out of date, because it looks specifically at whether the features are supported, so it doesn't care what the actual browser is.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution, but you will have to update your parser for the user agent string from time to time to include changes therein.
There is no agreed standard for use agent strings, so in general parsing the user agent string is quite hard and often comes down to lookup tables.

A more future-proof approach would be to detect the support of CSS animations on the client side using, e.g., [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) and then load the stylesheet based on the result. That way you don't care, if some browser developer wants to change the (structure of the) user agent string in the future.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure how css animations relate to tons of php code, but Modernizr.load is definitely the way to go: http://modernizr.com/docs/

Comment: +1. Use Modernizr. It is **by far** the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider using a Device Description Repository (DDR).  This is an application or Web Service that you can pass in an User Agent String and get a list of known capabilities for that User Agent.

The benefits to this is that you will not have to keep updating your own code as new User Agents come about.

I read about DDRs recently in [Dino Esposito's MSDN article on Mobile Site Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj190798.aspx).  He has an excellent write-up on the capabilities and nature of DDRs.

I realize you are doing PHP, but connecting / querying a DDR should be language independent.

Just a thought, hope this helps.